# How to enable php curl , phpinfo at google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

How to enable php curl , phpinfo    at google app engine.
when I run phpinfo at google app engine , I display an error

```
Message: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons. It can be re-enabled by adding it to the google_app_engine.enable_functions ini variable in your applications php.ini

Filename: controllers/welcome.php
```

I also getting an error

```
Message: php_sapi_name() has been disabled for security reasons. It can be re-enabled by adding it to the google_app_engine.enable_functions ini variable in your applications php.ini

Filename: core/URI.php
```

I already change google_appengine's php.ini file. But also getting error

my php.ini file:

```
; Re-enable these soft disabled functions for minishell users.
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "phpinfo, php_uname, php_sapi_name"
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name"
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "phpversion, phpinfo"
```

Answer (score 4):

You should combine all your google_app_engine.enable_functions directives into a single line, i.e.

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "phpinfo, php_uname, php_sapi_name, phpversion"
```

Comment: is `google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"` not enough to just enable curl?